# Share a .NET Membership Database with SharePoint?

Tags: .net, sharepoint

We have an FBA SharePoint implementation using a .NET Membership database. We would like to use this same database and collection of users for a new application. Has anyone tried this? I know in theory that it should work, but SharePoint can be finicky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally worry a bit too, but it is similar to worrying if Sharepoint shares Active Directory well with another .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SharePoint uses ASP.Net 2.0 to completely handle FBA membership, so in essence SharePoint is not directly touching the database and had no knowledge of it.  Your only worry should be ASP.Net 2.0 which seems less likely to be "finicky".